# getting the value from a jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm working on this slider.. that I want to use to change the margin of a  ..but my problem is getting the value out of it. even if I trie to show the value with an alert like this:

```
window.alert($( "#slider" ).val());
```

nothing shows up. Anyone an idea to what i;m doing wrong??

ThanX!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="./demo_files/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="./demo_files/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./demo_files/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>     
    #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; };
</style>


<script>
    function displayVals() {

        $( "#slider" ).slider();

        var step = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "step" );

        $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "step", 20 );  


        var singleValues = $("#slider").val();  
        $("p").html("<b>Single:</b> " + singleValues); 

        $("#slider").change(displayVals);                       
};

</script>
</head>

<div class="demo">

<div id="slider"></div>

</div><!-- End demo -->

<p></p>

<script> displayVals();</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
var singleValues = $('#slider').slider('value');
```

(or `'values'` if it's a multi-handled or range slider)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-value

Comment: Thanx @Alnitak.. tried this out but still it only gives back "0" no mather the slider change.... but it's correct of me to think the slider has a standard value from 1-100, i dont have to set this first right?

Comment: Think i got this part wrong..   $("#slider").change(displayVals);

Comment: got it! :) $( "#slider" ).slider({
       change: function(event, ui) {displayVals();}
   });